# Disabling and enabling a html input button

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a button like this:

```
<input id="Button" type="button" value="+" style="background-color:grey" onclick="Me();"/>
```

How can I disable and enable it when I want? I have tried `disabled="disable"` but enabling it back is a problem. I tried setting it back to false but that didn't enable it.

Comment: What do you mean enable it back? Once you disable it you can't re-enable it from the same method `Me()` I hope you know (because that's disabled)

Comment: I what I'm trying to do is to disable and enable the button when certain events happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTML button using JavaScript?](/q/3014649/90527)

Answer (score 711, accepted):

### Using Javascript

- Disabling a html button

  ```
  document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
  ```
- Enabling a html button

  ```
  document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
  ```
- [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/300/)

---

### Using jQuery

**All versions of jQuery prior to 1.6**

- Disabling a html button

  ```
  $('#Button').attr('disabled','disabled');
  ```
- Enabling a html button

  ```
  $('#Button').removeAttr('disabled');
  ```
- [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/)

**All versions of jQuery after 1.6**

- Disabling a html button

  ```
  $('#Button').prop('disabled', true);
  ```
- Enabling a html button

  ```
  $('#Button').prop('disabled', false);
  ```
- [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/1/)

**P.S. Updated the code based on [jquery 1.6.1 changes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/). As a suggestion, always use the latest jquery files and the `prop()` method.**

Comment: Do I need the attributes there for this to work? like disables="disable"

Comment: No, inside `$(document).ready` you can call `$('#Button').attr('disabled','disabled');`. This will disable the button on page load. And when certain events happen, you can call `$('#Button').removeAttr('disabled');` to enable it again...

Comment: how to add gray style if disabled?

Comment: @LeiYang you can add some css like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750390/1823841)

Comment: Just notice that true and false are boolean, not strings, as palash correctly wrote

Answer (score 37):

Since you are disabling it in the first place, the way to enable it is to set its `disabled` property as `false`.

To change its `disabled` property in Javascript, you use this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("Button");
btn.disabled = false;
```

And obviously to disable it again, you'd use `true` instead.

Since you also tagged the question with jQuery, you could use the `.prop` method. Something like:

```
var btn = $("#Button");
btn.prop("disabled", true);   // Or `false`
```

This is in the newer versions of jQuery. The older way to do this is to add or remove an attribute like so:

```
var btn = $("#Button");
btn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
// or
btn.removeAttr("disabled");
```

The mere presence of the `disabled` property disables the element, so you cannot set its value as "false". Even the following should disable the element

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" disabled="" />
```

You need to either remove the attribute completely **or** set its property.

Comment: what about if I want the button to be enabled initially then disabled later; I also tried enable="true". Is the enable the proper keyword??

Comment: @k.ken No, the keyword is "disabled". If you want the button enabled initially, don't put the attribute `disabled` in at all. Just use `<input type="button" value="Submit" />`. And when changing the status, use `.prop("disabled", true);` (or `false`)

Answer (score 27):

You can do this fairly easily with just Vanilla JavaScript, no libraries required.

**Enable a button**

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled=false;
```

**Disable a button**

```
 document.getElementById("Button").disabled=true;
```

No external libraries necessary.

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery you can do in a single line

```
//Enable
$('#Button').prop('disabled', false)

//Disable
$('#Button').prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: This has been mentioned in [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831737/6670491).

Answer (score 5):

the disable attribute only has one parameter. if you want to reenable it you have to remove the whole thing, not just change the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".btncancel").button({ disabled: true });
```

Here 'btncancel' is the class name of the button.

Answer (score 3):

While not directly related to the question, if you hop onto this question looking to disable something other than the typical input elements `button, input, textarea`, the syntax won't work.

To disable a div or a span, use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
document.querySelector('#somedivorspan').setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

P.S: Gotcha, only call this if you intend to disable. A bug in chrome Version 83 causes this to always disable even when the second parameter is false.

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery disable input will be simpler

```
Button.disabled=1;
```

```js
function dis() {
  Button.disabled= !Button.disabled;
}
```

```html
<input id="Button" type="button" value="+" style="background-color:grey" onclick="Me();"/>

<button onclick="dis()">Toggle disable</button>
```

Comment: Being doubtful, I was surprised that this actually works in Chrome, Edge, FF and Brave just tested.  Apparently it's not a recommended practice (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/1236837)  so I'm not likely to use it but an interesting find.

Comment: @KellyCode I agree with you that OP approach where he use elements ID's is not good in general (maybe acceptable for vey small projects or snippets for readable code shortening)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <!--Button Disable Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisableButton() {
            document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
    </script>
    <!--Button Disable Script-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Disabling/enabling an html input button with JavaScript:

(And React with refs. Replace "elementRef.current" with element selection if not using React)

```
 elementRef.current.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Enable:

```
 elementRef.current.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work .

**To Disable a button**

```
$('#btn_id').button('disable');
```

**To Enable a button**

```
$('#btn_id').button('enable');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to disable, No need to Find button with ID :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="btnAnything">My Button</button>

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
  e.disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -7):

Stick to php...

Why not only allow the button to appear once an above criteria is met.

```
<?
if (whatever == something) {
    $display = '<input id="Button" type="button" value="+" style="background-color:grey" onclick="Me();"/>';
    return $display;
}
?>
```