# Style disabled button with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the style of a button with an embedded image as seen in the following Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/xzBaZ/1/

In the example there are no images, I'm afraid.

I'm trying to:

1. Change the `background-color` of the button when it is disabled
2. Change the image in the button when it is disabled
3. Disable the hover effect when disabled
4. When you click on the image in the button and drag it, the image can be seen separately; I want to avoid that
5. The text on the button can be selected. I want to avoid that, too.

I tried doing in `button[disabled]`. But some effects could not be disabled. like
`top: 1px; position: relative;` and image.

Answer (score 629, accepted):

For the disabled buttons you can use the `:disabled` pseudo class. It works for all the elements that have a `disabled` API (typically form elements).

For browsers/devices supporting CSS2 only, you can use the `[disabled]` selector.

As with the image, don't put an image in the button. Use CSS `background-image` with `background-position` and `background-repeat`. That way, the image dragging will not occur.

**Selection problem:** here is a link to the specific question:

- [How to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

**Example for the disabled selector:**

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #0066cc;
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 1px solid #0099cc;
  background-color: #00aacc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
}

div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button> This is a working button </button>
</div>

<div>
  <button disabled> This is a disabled button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Applyable to CSS 2 or 3 (or both)?

Comment: As far as i know, the `:disabled` selector is a CSS3 selector. The `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-position` are working in CSS 2.

Comment: So maybe doing a :disabled, [disabled] would work in CSS2 & 3?

Comment: Just to note, the `="true"` part of `disabled="true"` is not what is making it disabled. You could use `disabled="false"` or `disabled="cat"` and it would still be disabled. Or simply have `disabled` with no value. That property can only be present/omitted in Html, or added via JavaScript with true/false

Comment: `:disabled` is a pseudo **class**, not a pseudo **element**. There is only three pseudo elements: `::before`, `::after`, and newly added `::marker`. You can easily tell one from the other because for pseudo elements they use `::` as a prefix, for pseudo classes `:`. I'm correcting that mistake.

Answer (score 118):

I think you should be able to select a disabled button using the following:

```
button[disabled=disabled], button:disabled {
    // your css rules
}
```

Comment: Can I disable the Hover ?? and I heard that will not work in IE6 ?

Comment: I don;t think you can but I'm not 100% sure. If you could also add a class of disabled onto disabled buttons then you could probably do it via that class.

Answer (score 52):

Add the below code in your page. No changes made to button events, to disable/enable the button simply add/remove the button class in JavaScript.

**Method 1**

```
 <asp Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="disabledContent" runat="server" />

<style type="text/css">
    .disabledContent 
    {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
    }

    .disabledContent > * 
    {
        pointer-events:none;
    }
</style>
```

**Method 2**

```
<asp Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn-disable" runat="server" />

<style type="text/css">
    .btn-disable
        {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;

        /*Button disabled - CSS color class*/
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: #ffffff;

        }
</style>
```

Comment: To feel button disabled add the below CSS code                                   color: #c0c0c0;
background-color: #ffffff;

Comment: sorry but this button looks different but still can be clicked and triggers onclick event in my FireFox, so I don't get it

Answer (score 13):

By **CSS:**

```
.disable{
   cursor: not-allowed;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Them you can add any decoration to that button.
For change the status you can use **jquery**

```
$("#id").toggleClass('disable');
```

Answer (score 11):

To apply grey button CSS for a disabled button.

```
button[disabled]:active, button[disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled] ,
button[disabled]:hover,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover
{
  border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
  color: GrayText;
  cursor: inherit;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For all of us using bootstrap, you can change the style by adding the "disabled" class and using the following:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button"class="btn disabled">Text</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn:disabled,
.btn.disabled{
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
.btn:disabled:hover,
.btn:disabled:focus,
.btn.disabled:hover,
.btn.disabled:focus {
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
```

Remember that adding the "disabled" class doesn't necessarily disable the button, for example in a submit form. To disable its behaviour use the disabled property:

```
<button type="button"class="btn disabled" disabled="disabled">Text</button>
```

A working fiddle with some examples is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s0gw53zu/).

Answer (score 8):

consider the following solution

```
.disable-button{ 
  pointer-events: none; 
  background-color: #edf1f2;
}
```

Comment: This solution will increase the weakness of the app/service that it is under building.

Comment: @FrancoGil you are right but this can be a way to achieve disable button

Answer (score 5):

When your button is disabled it directly sets the opacity. So first of all we have to set its opacity as

```
.v-button{
    opacity:1;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Need to apply css as belows:

```
button:disabled,button[disabled]{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    cursor:not-allowed !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

To make button disable dynamically, we can add this -

css -

```
button:disabled, button[disabled]{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

HTML-

```
<button [disabled]="true"> Button name </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="button"]:disabled,
input[type="submit"]:disabled,
input[type="reset"]:disabled,
{
  //  apply css here what u like it will definitely work...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you change your style (.css) file to SASS (.scss) use:

```
button {
  background-color: #007700;
  &:disabled {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution

```
Button{

&:disabled{

Opacity:0.8;
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can disable buttons by pass value in css for disable status.

html

```
<button
   [disabled]="true">
</button>
```

css

```
.button-action.disabled {
  // some css
}
```