# Dynamically disabled button not changing visually?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

So basically we have a button that when clicked, its value should change and it should be disabled. Our button goes from
 `<input class="saveButton" name="yt26" type="button" value="save" id="yt26">`
to
`<input class="saveButton" name="yt26" type="button" value="saved" id="yt26" disabled>`

Unfortunately, the button does not change visually until the page is refreshed. We're changing the button using the `$(this).attr("disabled","disabled")` We have also tried `$(this).prop("disabled", true)` and `$(this).prop("disabled","disabled")` none of which seem to work. If you are familiar with Yii, the whole button code is posted below:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
            'save', 
            Yii::app()->createUrl('dashboard/savelink'),
            array( // ajax options
                'type' => 'POST',
                'context' => "js:this",
                'success' => 'js:function() {$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); $(this).val("saved") ;}',
                'data' => array(
                    'commentLink' => $commentLink
                )
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'saveButton'
            )
        );
```

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TaDZs/ - not reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the disabled pseudo. that's how your browser normally change the look of a disabled input or button `:disabled`. set the style to your preference. None the less put this in your global css or the css file you are using

```
input:disabled, button:disabled{
  color:graytext;
  background: buttonface;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the `$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled")` in beforeSend option of the ajax.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
        'save', 
        Yii::app()->createUrl('dashboard/savelink'),
        array( // ajax options
            'type' => 'POST',
            'context' => "js:this",
            'beforeSend => js: function(){$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); },
            'success' => 'js:function() { $(this).val("saved") ;}',
            'data' => array(
                'commentLink' => $commentLink
            )
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'saveButton'
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the style still does not change (The attribute is still added however.)

Comment: For the disabled buttons you can use the `:disabled` pseudo-element in your css file. Although, it is only working for browsers that supports CSS3 selectors.

   `input:disabled{ color:graytext; background: buttonface; border:1px solid; }`

Comment: See this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-css] I think you have the same issue.