# HTML add help symbol(button) beside disabled option

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to know how you could add a help symbol beside a disabled option in a dropdown in html, if possible. I would like it so that when you click on the symbol it then tells you why that option has been disabled. Something similar to the dropdown below.

[image]

This is the basic code I have for the dropdown right now.

```
<select name="description" rows="4" class="form-control">
                <option value="RhinoTab"><?php echo _l('estimate_table_option1_1'); ?></option>
                <option value="RTi"><?php echo _l('estimate_table_option1_2'); ?></option>
                <option value="Magical Shit" disabled>Magical Shit</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style disabled button with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

Comment: Looks like they want to fully disable the option. I want to add a symbol beside the option when it is disabled so that when you click the symbol it states why the option is disabled.

Comment: provide your css code too with snippet !

Comment: The CSS was already done for the site this is on so i'll have to track that section down. I'm not all that great with CSS.

Comment: this is impossible but you can do it some way using css

Comment: Could something like this be done, except on the click event it shows the message? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an example I was able to use as a work around to get my project working. Instead of having an icon it is when you click on the "disabled" option but it will do something close enough to what I was looking for.

```
 $(function(){
    var options_sel_idx = 0;

    $("#options").on("change", this, function(event) {
        if($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).hasClass("disabled")) {
            alert("a");
            this.selectedIndex = options_sel_idx;
        } else {
            options_sel_idx = this.selectedIndex;
        }
    });
});

<style type="text/css">
    .disabled {color:#808080;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Options 1</option>
  <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 2</option>
  <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 3</option>
  <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 4</option>
</select>
```