# Django: Wrong rendering HTML (/css) file

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to set different styles for buttons depending on whether they are activated or not. So I do it as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css) (see code below), which works fine if I open the HTML file directly in my Webbrowser: The working button is blue while the disabled one is grey.

Now, I try to access the site via the IP of the django server and it doesn't work. The buttons are standard buttons and do not have any design applied by the CSS code. However, things like background - which I set in the CSS file - are working properly. This is how it looks:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I include the css file as follows:`<link href="../../static/myApp/mainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Here is the code:

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #0066cc;
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 1px solid #0099cc;
  background-color: #00aacc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button> This is a working button </button>
</div>

<div>
  <button disabled="true"> This is a disabled button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check CSS file is loading or not from server? what is status code of CSS file?

Comment: How are you including the css in the page? How are you serving that css file?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR How can I get the status code?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'myApp/mainStyle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Use above code for serve css file in template.

Comment: Do I have to edit anything in the setup.py ,... so that his works? For me, there is no change when trying this code.

Comment: You have to define STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL  in settings.py