# Is there a way to disable a button using jQuery without making it transparent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery in a project so I figured I leverage some of its specific methods. Anyway I have two buttons and upon a certain condition I'd like to disable it. Like so:

```
if (...condition...) {
   $('button#submit, #hint').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

However it makes the buttons transparent—

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Rather than going through the trouble of creating a specific class does anyone know if jQuery have an alternative—which maybe makes it grey and 
rather than transparent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i mean.. you can apply styles with jquery, but styling the disabled button would likely make more sense. jQuery shouldn't be styling your page.

Comment: _Rather than going through the trouble of creating a specific class_, this is the best solution though. Why it does not fit your needs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css

Comment: In browser dev tools elements inspector - Inspect the css rules that apply when it is disabled and modify the css rules affecting it

Answer (score 2):

You can try styling the `disabled` CSS selector.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(e){
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
:disabled{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Button
</button>
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a down vote, either. It gives the functionality the OP asked for.

Comment: .attr is the wrong method to change the disabled property.

Comment: @KevinB It may not be best practice, but it works here.

Comment: @War10ck thanks for that. I obviously don't use jQuery that much :P

Comment: @freginold it would only work once, until you wanted to make it not disabled.

Comment: @JosanIracheta No worries. It's easy to confuse the two.

Comment: @War10ck btw `disabled,true` and `disabled,disabled` both work ;-)

Comment: [this discussion has been had already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to style the button per your liking.

```
$('button').on('click',function(e){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   $(this).css('background-color','#CCCCCC');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. Don't disable the button at all, style the button yourself and "kill" the button's ability to perform any actions.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);

function btnClick(){
  console.log("Business as usual.");
}

var chk = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");

chk.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(this.checked){
    // Kill the click event and alter the style
    btn.classList.add("disabled");
  } else {
    // Restore the look
    btn.classList.remove("disabled");    
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events:none;
  color:#808080;
  
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
<input type="checkbox" value="disable">Disable button
```

Comment: i don't like it.

Comment: So? It solves the problem with simple standard code. What's not to like? Maybe I'll start "not liking" your valid answers?

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a downvote... it does exactly what the OP asked for, with a clear explanation.

Comment: an answer working, and an answer being good/useful, are two different things.

Comment: @War10ck The `disabled` pseudo-class is not at all for this scenario because the OP doesn't like what making the element disabled does. Therefore, a work-around is needed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It most certainly is for this scenario. The OP doesn't like the way it looks: _"However it makes the buttons transparent...which maybe makes it grey and rather than transparent?"_ Change the style not the functionality...

Comment: @KevinB Did you wake up and decide to be a troll today? This is a very good and simple answer. The OP is telling us that `disabled` isn't going to work for them. This is the only other way to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: clearly it isn't the only way to accomplish it, there's a far simpler method posted in the other answer.