# Change button color only on disabled

Tags: html, css

I've around 50* buttons and I want to change the style only for not disabled button

```
button{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: very low quality
This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style disabled button with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **:disabled** selector.

```
button:disabled {
    background: white;
}
```