# how to disable icon of particular data from table list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of data coming in table. Each data shows status of data and has play icon. I want that when someone clicks on play icon that icon becomes disable until response from api comes out. i have tried to implement it but

*my component.html code*

```
   <table class="table tabs">
  <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Id</th>
 <th>Status</th>
 <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor=" let con of getInfo | paginate : { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
  currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems }; let i = index" >
  <td>{{ con.GroupName }}</td>
  <td>{{ con.Id }}</td> 
 <td>{{ con.Status }}</td>
   <td>
  <i class="fa fa-play" (click)="play(con.Id)"></i>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

*my component.ts code*

```
     play(idx: number) {
   this.service.getDataIndo(id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
  this.getAnaInfo =res
   })
  }
```

Comment: in here you will have a list of button do you want to disable all button or just the one you click on it

Comment: i want to disable one button on click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way is to create an object and track the clicked of button by the passed id.

```js
clickedStatus:{[id:string]:boolean} ={};

play(idx: number) {
  this.clickedStatus[idx] = true;
  this.service.getDataIndo(id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
       this.getAnaInfo =res;
       this.clickedStatus[idx] = false;
   })
}
```

template

```html
  <button type="button" (click)="play(con.Id)" [disabled]="clickedStatus[con.Id]">
           <i class="fa fa-play" ></i>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the index of the item in your play function as well,

```
play(id: number, index:number) {
this.getInfo[index]['disabled'] = true;
   this.service.getDataIndo(id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
   this.getAnaInfo =res;
   this.getInfo[index]['disabled'] = false;
   })
}
```

and in your template, use conditional ngClass

```
<i class="fa fa-play" (click)="play(con.Id,i)" [ngClass]="con.disabled?'disabled' : 'active'"></i>
```

and

```
<tr *ngFor=" let con of getInfo;let i =index | paginate : { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
  currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems }; let i = index" >
  <td>{{ con.GroupName }}</td>
  <td>{{ con.Id }}</td> 
 <td>{{ con.Status }}</td>
   <td>
  <i class="fa fa-play" (click)="play(con.Id,i)"></i> //index is passed here
 </td>
 </tr>
```

For displaying the button/icon as disabled, You will have to write some CSS

[Consider this solution for styling the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

Comment:  hi , index can be changed in case of filter as example so a better way is to use id as it 's unique

Comment: Yes, your statement completely makes sense. I think your comment will remain valid if the pagination is also there on the data. Neelam If your page also have filters, than solution given in the answer by @malbarmavi will make complete sense

Comment: When i am implementing this it effects the whole table icon

Comment: It shouldn't do that, can you please share your updated code.