# How to disable a button with style (CSS) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have here a simple script that will disable other buttons onclick of a button. For example, if a user clicks `sample disable`, it will disable all specified buttons.

Right now, it does this just fine. It disables all the other buttons. However, my problem is, those buttons with CSS class "cbtn" aren't looking like they are disabled when in fact, they are.

What I wanted to accomplish is: to make the buttons `(a)` through `(j)` retain their style (CSS), but appear disabled just like how `1`, through `4` looks when they are disabled.

```js
function resetallamnotes() {
  document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;

  document.getElementById("(a)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(b)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(c)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(d)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(e)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(f)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(g)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(h)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("*(i)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(j)").disabled = false;
}

function amnotesDisable1st() {
  document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(a)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(b)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(c)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(d)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(e)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(f)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(g)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(h)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("*(i)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(j)").disabled = true;
}
```

```css
.cbtn {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e0f2f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cbtn:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.cbtn:active {
  background-color: #e0f7fa;
  transform: translateY(1px);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 1px #666666;
}
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" onclick="resetallamnotes()">Reset</button>
<br><br>
<button id="1st" onclick="amnotesDisable1st()">sample disable</button>
<button id="2nd" onclick="disable2nd()">2</button>
<button id="3rd" onclick="disable3rd()">3</button>
<button id="4th" onclick="disable4th()">4</button>
<br><br>
<button id='(a)' class="cbtn">(a)</button>
<button id='(b)' class="cbtn">(b)</button>
<button id='(c)' class="cbtn">(c)</button>
<button id='(d)' class="cbtn">(d)</button>
<button id='(e)' class="cbtn">(e)</button>
<button id='(f)' class="cbtn">(f)</button>
<button id='(g)' class="cbtn">(g)</button>
<button id='(h)' class="cbtn">(h)</button>
<button id='*(i)' class="cbtn">(i)</button>
<button id='(j)' class="cbtn">(j)</button>
```

Thank you thank you in advance! Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style disabled button with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

Comment: You should really refactor to use a common class or an array of IDs and a loop. That repetition is gross.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I glanced over it and it does seem what I'm looking for. I will try it out a bit later to check if I can work it out using that method. Thank you!

Comment: @isherwood I agree sir. But it's what I can only do right now. Still a beginner in coding, and trying to build a use-able tool for work. I can't tweak it to look better just yet. But thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:disabled` pseudo class to define how disabled buttons are supposed to differ visually:

```
.cbtn:disabled {
  opacity: 0.33;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
const buttonIds = ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","(a)","(b)","(c)","(d)","(e)","(f)","(g)","(h)","*(i)","(j)"];

function toggleDisabled(on) {
  for (const id of buttonIds) {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.disabled = typeof on !== 'boolean' ? !el.disabled : on;
  }
}
```

```css
.cbtn {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e0f2f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cbtn:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.cbtn:active {
  background-color: #e0f7fa;
  transform: translateY(1px);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 1px #666666;
}

.cbtn:disabled {
  opacity: 0.33;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" onclick="toggleDisabled(false)">Reset</button>
<br><br>
<button id="1st" onclick="toggleDisabled(true)">sample disable</button>
<button id="2nd">2</button>
<button id="3rd">3</button>
<button id="4th">4</button>
<br><br>
<button id='(a)' class="cbtn">(a)</button>
<button id='(b)' class="cbtn">(b)</button>
<button id='(c)' class="cbtn">(c)</button>
<button id='(d)' class="cbtn">(d)</button>
<button id='(e)' class="cbtn">(e)</button>
<button id='(f)' class="cbtn">(f)</button>
<button id='(g)' class="cbtn">(g)</button>
<button id='(h)' class="cbtn">(h)</button>
<button id='*(i)' class="cbtn">(i)</button>
<button id='(j)' class="cbtn">(j)</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This is exactly what I need and want! Yahooo!

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the base `cbtn` rules to only those buttons that aren't [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled):

```css
.cbtn:not(:disabled) { 
  /* ... */
}
```

```js
function resetallamnotes() {
  document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;

  document.getElementById("(a)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(b)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(c)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(d)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(e)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(f)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(g)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(h)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("*(i)").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("(j)").disabled = false;
}

function amnotesDisable1st() {
  document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(a)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(b)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(c)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(d)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(e)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(f)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(g)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(h)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("*(i)").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("(j)").disabled = true;
}
```

```css
.cbtn:not([disabled]) {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e0f2f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cbtn:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.cbtn:active {
  background-color: #e0f7fa;
  transform: translateY(1px);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 1px #666666;
}
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" onclick="resetallamnotes()">Reset</button>
<br><br>
<button id="1st" onclick="amnotesDisable1st()">sample disable</button>
<button id="2nd" onclick="disable2nd()">2</button>
<button id="3rd" onclick="disable3rd()">3</button>
<button id="4th" onclick="disable4th()">4</button>
<br><br>
<button id='(a)' class="cbtn">(a)</button>
<button id='(b)' class="cbtn">(b)</button>
<button id='(c)' class="cbtn">(c)</button>
<button id='(d)' class="cbtn">(d)</button>
<button id='(e)' class="cbtn">(e)</button>
<button id='(f)' class="cbtn">(f)</button>
<button id='(g)' class="cbtn">(g)</button>
<button id='(h)' class="cbtn">(h)</button>
<button id='*(i)' class="cbtn">(i)</button>
<button id='(j)' class="cbtn">(j)</button>
```

Comment: `:disabled` there is a pseudo class for it.

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for taking the time to set this up. I was hoping if it's possible to keep the styling (background color, border, border-radius, etc..) and also look disabled or look unclickable.

Comment: @ixcode You specified the exact opposite explicitly *to make the buttons (a) through (j) retain their style (CSS), but appear disabled just like how 1, through 4 looks when they are disabled*

Comment: Then try like this `.cbtn:hover:not(:disabled){ }` and `.cbtn:active:not(:disabled){ } `

Comment: Using the tools provided (`:disabled` class or `[disabled]` attribute selector), you can style the buttons however you like.

Comment: @connexo I couldn't find the right word that would mean "appear unclickable" just like ```1``` through ```4```. But it's really what I'm trying to achieve, sir.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for all your input and suggestions! I can work on this now. Yehey! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @connexo. Forgot about that. Answer updated accordingly.