# Button style prevents the button to be disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I head to a strange problem today that the style prevents a button to be disabled. I removed the styles and the button worked(disabled) correctly. I'm working with react which I gave a class to the button. I also tried inline style but it wasn't helpful too. (Maybe it is because of react). It also shows the button like this `<button class="global-delete-icon" disabled>` in dev tools but it's not actually. I tried to try these solutions but weren't helpful.

```
1. <button className="global-delete-icon" disabled>

2. <button ... disabled="disabled">

3. <button ... disabled={true}>

4. <button ... disabled="true">
```

I'm using SCSS to style so I thought maybe the problem is because of this, but it wasn't actually.

```
.global-delete-icon {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    margin-inline: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 100ms ease-in-out;

    i {
        margin: 7.5px;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: #b8524e;
    }
}
```

I haven't seen something like this before and already reviewed this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css) but it wasn't helpful.

**It's working fine giving style and disabling the button on StackOverflow's code runner(without react).**

Comment: Hi! Could you include more of the actual code block that you're having trouble with?

Comment: does not seem possible.... Probably need to see actual code that reproduces the problem

Comment: In HTML, "boolean" attributes mean you put just `disabled`, **not** `disabled="true"` (though you _can_ also do `disabled="disabled"` for XHTML).

Comment: The CSS class attribute is `class=""`, **not** `classname=""`.

Comment: So does the button just not look disabled, or can you click it and the click-handler gets called?

Comment: You should style disabled buttons using the `:disabled` pseudo-class selector.

Comment: A great thing to disable a button click via css you can add property { pointer-events : none } after make it auto ! It work s perfect ....

Comment: The actual code is not needed. These are the needed ones.

Comment: @Sanmeet Does this also disables the events? I mean this is the same as *disabled*?

Comment: @Sanmeet No, that doesn't work "perfectly", quite the opposite: it only disables interaction from the mouse pointer: so you can still interact with the button using your keyboard, such as using Tab + Space or Tab + Enter. And the browser may even auto-focus the button on page-load so if the user accidentally presses their enter button on their keyboard then that will also invoke the button's `click` event-listener or default action.

Comment: The disabled is not going to override the hover CSS.... did you want to style that? https://jsfiddle.net/epascarello/dezt9xaw/1/

Comment: @epascarello I think this is helpful. I would accept this answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a test and I see that the button is actually disabled, but the CSS is still being applied and makes it look like it is still enabled. So you can create one or more :disabled rules to change how it looks.

```
.global-delete-icon {        
    &:disabled {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }
    
    &:hover:disabled {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }
}
```