After each click, have text animation appear and fade? (html, css, javascript)
As this code is now, I must press twice to have the text appear and fade.
How can I press the button only once to have the "Added!" text appear and fade? I would like this to happen for every time I click the button (even if the user clicks WHILE the text is fading, it should start from fully visible to fading).
I have tried focus with CSS. I have also tried rearranging javascript code, as well as inserting a while loop in the javascript, but I must be doing something wrong.
Thanks


  function cartAdded() {
    var text = document.getElementById("added-notification");
    if (text.style.display === "none") {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  .added-fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    animation: fadeOut 1s ease-out;

  }

  @keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      display: none;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 0.5;
      display: block;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
  }
  <button type='button' onclick="cartAdded()">Click me</button>
  <p id='added-notification' class="added-fade-out">Added!</p>



EDIT: This was one of those questions I did not know how to ask as I was unaware of the terminology to use. Later, after much searching, I found a solution that will match my question more precisely.
Basically, the original question also needed the animation to restart after each click, not only when the animation ends. This code matches more closely to what I'm trying to accomplish (stack overflow: Animation should play every time you click the button)
Animation replays after each click:


  function showMessage() {
    let message = document.getElementById('child');

    if (message.classList.contains('d-none')) {
      message.classList.remove('d-none');
    }

    // message.classList.add('d-none');
    message.style.animation = 'none';
    message.offsetHeight;
    message.style.animation = null;
  }
  .parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  @keyframes msgSuccess {
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    animation-name: msgSuccess;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .d-none {
    display: none;
  }
  <button onclick="showMessage()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child d-none">Message</div>
  </div>




you need to use animationend event to remove your fade Out


const
  notificationButton = document.querySelector('#notification-btn')
, pNotificationText  = document.querySelector('#notification-text')
  ;

notificationButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
  notificationButton.disabled = true;
  pNotificationText.classList.replace('noDisplay','show-fade-out')
  })
pNotificationText.addEventListener('animationend', () =>
  {
  notificationButton.disabled = false;
  pNotificationText.classList.replace('show-fade-out','noDisplay') 
  })
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
  }
.show-fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut 1s ease-out forwards;
  }
@keyframes fadeOut {
  100% { opacity: 0; }
  }
<button id="notification-btn">Click me</button>
<p id='notification-text' class="noDisplay" > Added! </p>




Thanks! I wasn't intending for the button to fade, but this may be better because it visibly dissuades and does not allow the user to click again until the fade process is complete. My goal is to make this an add-to-shopping-cart process, so this can work, or having the "Added!" text fully visible to fade after each click (even if clicked while text is fading). I'll give it a try!

@bkw the button doesn't fade, it is just the default styling for element button on disabled mode, You can customize this styling with css -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css

Also, thanks for the animationend event pointer, which I was not aware of

You have to explicitly set the display property to none initially. Otherwise, text.style.display will return an empty string.


var text = document.getElementById("added-notification");
text.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  text.style.display = "none"
})

function cartAdded() {
  if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
.added-fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  animation: fadeOut 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<button type='button' onclick="cartAdded()">Click me</button>
<p id='added-notification' class="added-fade-out" style="display: none">Added!</p>




@MisterJojo what??? I didn't understand a thing you just said.

That is not OP's objective.

Thank you! If I click again while the "Added!" text is fading it disappears instead of starting from fully visible to fading again. I suppose what I meant to ask is, how can it start from fully visible to fade after each click (even if clicked when the text is fading)? For this, I apologize if my question was not clear.

Good solution! @bkw, no worries, it happens sometimes; I can see you have updated your question.
