# jquery when checkbox is not checked hide a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a `textbox` and a `checkbox`, when the `checkbox` is unchecked, I need to disabled the `textbox` and when the user selects the `checkbox`, I want to re-enable the `textbox`.

I tried this:

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<div class="checkConfiguration">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="stopGeneralNumber" Text="General Number"   CssClass="cbStopReason" Checked="false" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
 $('.cbStopReason').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            alert("now checked");
            $(this).nextAll("input").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            alert("now un checked");
            $(this).nextAll("input").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        }
    })
```

The `jQuery` code is already in `document ready function`, but the problem is that my code works good to disable the `textbox`, but it doesn't work to re-enable it, what wrong did I do please?

**Update 1: This is the actual HTML that is being generated**

```
 <div class="configurationData">
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopUrgentNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopUrgentNumber"><label for="stopUrgentNumber">Urgent Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl17" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopNurseNurse" type="checkbox" name="stopNurseNurse"><label for="stopNurseNurse">Nurse Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl18" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopScheduledNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopScheduledNumber"><label for="stopScheduledNumber">Scheduled Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl19" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopClockNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopClockNumber"><label for="stopClockNumber">Clock Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl20" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopLastCheckNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopLastCheckNumber"><label for="stopLastCheckNumber">Last Check Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl21" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopArrivalNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopArrivalNumber"><label for="stopArrivalNumber">Arrival Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl22" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkConfiguration">
                                <span class="cbStopReason"><input id="stopGeneralNumber" type="checkbox" name="stopGeneralNumber"><label for="stopGeneralNumber">General Number</label></span>
                                <input name="ctl23" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$(this).prop('checked')` instead?

Comment: @BryanDowning i just tried your suggestion, i put your code in the `if` statement and I still have the same problem that is described on the question

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/wcktqdnt/

Comment: @BryanDowning but you have used a different html that mine, i updated the question and added the generated html

Comment: This may help:

  http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-button

Comment: @PhilipClegg I will try your suggestion, however, the problem is that the `alert` always shows the false message,

Comment: @PhilipClegg i already put the html that is being generated, the one you gave me is different that the html i am using, could you check please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your OP, it looks like your binding on your span.  Changed it to bind on your checkbox.  Also changed the bind from click to change.  http://jsfiddle.net/0fL0pumf/1/

```
$('#stopGeneralNumber').on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $this.parent().nextAll("input").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $this.parent().nextAll("input").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Reduced the javascript...

```
$('#stopGeneralNumber').on('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().nextAll("input").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Generic to use the class, but not the id of the checkbox.  Just uses a different selector.

```
$('.cbStopReason > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().nextAll("input").prop("disabled", !$this.is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: i can't use the `id`, i must use the `class` because i have too many check box and i want to treat them all using the `class`, i just updated my question to give u the five checkbox that i have

Comment: i tried your code, and i still face the same proboem, i am thinking maybe because you tried your code on just one checkbox while i have fife of them, i updated the quesiotn to give u my generated html

Answer (score 0):

In the rendered code, you no longer have a checkbox with the class `cbStopReason` -- that class is applied to the `span` and the span will never be `checked`.

One fix is to change the conditional to:

```
$(this).find("input").attr('checked')
```

Comment: could you give me a working jsfiddle? or at least tell me what would my code look like for the true and false condisions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9vLtpqtt/5/ simply add `.find("input")` before the `.attr` in your `if`

Comment: the code you put is not working on my machine though it is working good on jsfiddle, i can't find the problem, i gave u the code, how can it works on jsffidle but not on my machine please?

Comment: I tried to do this `alert($(this).find("input").attr('checked'));` before the `if` statement, and i kept getting `undifinied` printed

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the event handler to the wrong element (selector). Also, you can reduce your code quite a lot.

I would do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    // On the checkbox click.
    // Here I would give these checkboxes a particular class
    // to use on the selector.
    $('.checkConfiguration input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
        // Go to its parent and look for the input.
        // Enable/disable it according to the checkbox 
        // checked value.
        $(this).closest('.checkConfiguration')
            .find('input[type=text]')
            .prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jo4ptseg/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Use `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` instead.

Comment: I already did that before asking the question here, and I still have the same problem that is described on the question

Comment: But does the browser shows the alert when you activate the checkbox?

Comment: the alert is always the one that is written in the `false` part