# disable enable button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working javascript version to disable/enable a from button but I can not get it working using jQuery.

My jsfiddle has both versions. The javascript version is commented out.

```
    //NOT WORKING jQuery
   function controls(id) {
   if (id === "button_start") {
    //$('button_start').prop('disabled','disabled');
    // $('button_stop').removeProp('disabled','disabled');

    // testing
    $('#button_start').on('click',function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $('#button_stop').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeProp('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    //console.log(id);

   } else {
    //$('button_stop').prop('disabled','disabled');
    //$('button_start').removeProp('disabled','disabled');

     // testing
    $('#button_stop').click(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $('#button_start').click(function(){
        $(this).removeProp('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
      //console.log(id);
        }
    }
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/w2u8eskv/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The disabled *property* is a boolean. Set it to true or false, don't set it to a string or try to remove it.

Comment: This question would be easier to understand if you copied the working JavaScript from the fiddle to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might not solve your problem, however you are using the `removeProp` method wrong. According to the jQuery documentation, removeProp takes only one attribute

```
.removeProp( propertyName )
propertyName
Type: String
The name of the property to remove.
```

In your example, I would change your lines that look like this

```
$('#button_start').click(function(){
    $(this).removeProp('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

to this

```
$('#button_start').click(function(){
    $(this).removeProp('disabled');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

Also, remember that id elements must start with the `#` sign. You had that in your OP but not in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.

```
$('button_start')
```

should be

```
$('#button_start') 
   ^--------------- Missing id selector syntax
```

Then you need to include the jQuery library for the fiddle to start working.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style:

```
#button_start:disabled{background:blue;opacity:0.3;}
```

and your script:

```
function controls(id) {

    if (id === "button_start") {
        $('#button_start').attr('disabled','disabled');      
        $('#button_stop').removeProp('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#button_stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#button_start').removeProp('disabled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery versions after 1.6:

```
$('#button_start').prop('disabled', false); //to enable and pass true to disable
```

For other options and versions, look at this SO answer [Disabling and enabling an HTML input button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831737/977344)