# Disable ASP.NET buttons while background processing is going on

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, html

I am creating a website wherein I am displaying a gridview and below it I have a button upon whose click I want to hide all the buttons on the web page till the processing completes. I have tried through code behind and its hiding it after the OnClick function completes its execution but what I want is to disable the input for the time in which the OnClick function is executing only.

Below is my piece of code,

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    b.Enabled = false;
// processing goes here
}
```

and my button is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="SyncButton1" 
    Text="Sync With AMS"
            CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="ShowProgress()" 
    OnClick="Button2_Click"
            Visible="false" />
```

Below is my piece of JS,

```
function ShowProgress() {
    $("#form1 :input").prop('readonly', true);
    var modal = $('<div />');
    modal.addClass("modal");
    $('body').append(modal);
    var loading = $(".loading");
    loading.show();
    var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
    var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
    loading.css({ top: top, left: left });

}
```

I am still able to click on the buttons which should not happen for the while when my OnClick function is executing.

Can anyone suggest some other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable enable button using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214150/disable-enable-button-using-jquery)

Comment: You're on the right lines with the OnClientClick which doesn't wait for execution. I think it may be the JS that is causing problems, you need to disable it rather than making it read only.

Comment: Blocking DOM and disabling elements are ui concerns,on your code, when you click button you call both client code and server side code, so when click button you immediately make a request to server, your client side event becomes useless. What you should do is to remove `OnClick="Button2_Click"` attribute and only work with `OnClientClick`, for your ui purposes.

Comment: @BinaryDebug I tried using ("disabled",true) and it is disabling all the input but then my server side code is not getting hit.

Comment: @ibubi I have to go server side as my work is not related to only UI hence, cannot execute everything at client side.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onbeforeunload` is called before any post back.

Try using using it like below to disable or hide button as soon as a target button is clicked

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function DisableButton() {
        document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using you approach and it is disabling all the input but my server side code is not getting hit then.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if u bind some JavaScript function in `OnClientClick` of a button then execution priority is as below;

1. `OnClientClick` then
2. `Onclick`

That's why although you are made the button enable false as above its not working because first `onClientClick` event is executing.

So, for that solution is u have to call that JavaScript function in side your button click event instead on bind into `OnClientClick`.

Refer the example below:

```
    //Javascript function
    function ShowProgress() {
            $("#form1 :input").prop('readonly', true);
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });

        }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Enabled = false;
       // processing goes here
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopUp();", true);
    }
```

and button as follows:

```
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="SyncButton1" 
     Text="Sync With AMS" CausesValidation="true" 
       OnClick="Button2_Click" Visible="false" />
```

I think it will solve your problem still, if you face some problem let me know.

Comment: Tried this approach but what it's doing is that it completes all the processing and then the loading pop up is showing. :-(

Comment: inside the button click event before b.Enabled=false; put that clientscript thing.... then try to build.....its working code I already implemented this...may be I think u miss some minor thing..just try the above step n lemme know....meanwhile i m xploring the cause for the problem u r facing.,...thnq

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is close, but not quite.

The `OnClientClick` will run before posting back to the server for `OnClick`. Setting the buttons to `readonly` will **not** stop them from being clickable.

Use the attribute selector to select `input type="button"` and `input type="submit"`

Try the following

```
function ShowProgress() {
    //Sets fields to readonly, note that this misses selects
    $("#form1 :input").prop('readonly', true);

    //Disable the buttons - Note the attribute selector
    $("#form1 :input[type=button],#form1 :input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);

    /*No Change to Modal stuff, removed for brevity*/

}
```

You can't disable all inputs, as the value for disabled inputs are not returned to the server.