# Rails: turn off submit button waiting for Braintree to finish its processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit, wait, braintree

I have a Rails-driven website.  One of the pages uses Braintree to do credit card processing.

It sometimes takes a few seconds for the Braintree credit card transaction to be processed by Braintree.

#### Question

What I'd like to do is

1. disable the submit button while Braintree does it's processing (sometimes as much as 15 seconds but typically about 5 seconds), as
   well as,
2. put up a "spinner" indicating the user should not do anything while
   we wait for Braintree to finish its work.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can all use `data-distable-with` attribute on submit button

Answer (score 0):

For custom ui you can basic structure from clinet side is:-

```
var client_token = "<%= @token %>"
  var checkout;
  braintree.setup(client_token, "custom", {
  option-1,
  option-2,
  option-3,
  option-......
});
```

// should have a html div with spinner which should be by default hide,and on click payment button it will show.

// Adds click event listener to your own PayPal button of choice

```
$('#spinner_div').hide();
$('#my-button-element').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  checkout.paypal.initAuthFlow();
  $('#spinner_div').show();
  return false;
});
```

References: -

1- https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#onpaymentmethodreceived-details-object

2- https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/javascript/v2

3- https://harryxue.net/using-a-custom-html-form-with-braintree/

4- https://gist.github.com/danielwu426/70eac6b34ab7491610f0

5- https://github.com/braintree/braintree_rails_example

6- https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/javascript/v2

Answer (score 0):

I added an id (ralph_submit_button) to the submit:

```
<button id="ralph_submit_button" class="button" type="submit" style="color: white;"><span>Approve Transaction</span></button>
```

I modified the recommended javascript as

```
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
  var client_token = "<%= @client_token %>";

  braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: client_token,
    container: '#bt-dropin',
    paymentOptionPriority: ['card'],
    // paypal: {
    //   flow: 'vault'
    // }
  }, function (createErr, instance) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      <%# See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button %>
      document.getElementById("ralph_submit_button").disabled = true;

      event.preventDefault();

      instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error', err);
          return;
        }

        // Add the nonce to the form and submit
        document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
        form.submit();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Try as I might, I could not get a spinner to work with Braintree.

Others might want to look at https://github.com/tcannonfodder/submit-button-spinner/blob/master/demo.html .  You might have more success than I.  The code in https://github.com/tcannonfodder/submit-button-spinner/blob/master/demo.html seems to work well but I was unable to integrate that code into my Braintree code.