# JavaScript button Enable and Disable

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Hello there so I'm making a remake of the popular game cookie clicker but I'm having some issues so here is what I need help with

So as you know in the game cookie clicker, they have power up buttons and those buttons disable them selfs when you do not have enough money to buy it

and that's what I need help with I want to be able to have the power-up buttons disabled and when I have enough money make them auto enable

so here I'll put some example code to sort of explain it a bit better

### code:

```
if (cookies >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("IdName").disabled = false;
}else {
    document.getElementById("IdName").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: what is cookies?

Comment: Please post a **[mcve]**.  As it stands there are too many things that could be wrong with the posted code, which makes it difficult to be of clear help.

Comment: I am not able to replicate ,need more insights

Comment: IdName is a button?

Comment: cookies are the number of cookies they have clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling and enabling a html input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function evalButton() {
  var cookies = document.getElementById("cookies").value;
  cookies = parseInt(cookies, 10);
  console.log(cookies);
  if (cookies >= 10) {
      document.getElementById("IdName").disabled = false;
  }else {
      document.getElementById("IdName").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#IdName {
  background: red;
}

#IdName:disabled {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<input id="cookies" onkeyup="evalButton()"/>
<button id="IdName">Press me</button>
```

Your code is working fine-- and cookies value can be derived in the function or passed as an argument.  A bit of CSS can be used to give visual cues to the disabled state.