# Unable to disable a button element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to disable a button using the `getElementById()` method.  I am looking for inspiration as to what I am doing wrong because I use it to enable a button but I cannot seem to be able to disable it.

I have tried calling the method in different ways:

```
document.getElementById('wsSubmit').disabled = false;
document.getElementById("wsSubmit").disabled = false;
document.getElementById('#wsSubmit').disabled = false;
document.getElementById("#wsSubmit").disabled = false;
document.getElementById(buttons[0]).disabled = false;
```

Button in question:

```
<input class="button" type="button" id="wsSubmit" onclick="closeWindowDWSC();" value="Submit" disabled>
```

I want the button to become enabled.

Comment: Have you checked the button exists when the code runs? What errors are thrown?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button

Comment: When is your method call executed? Is the DOM ready?

Comment: document.getElementById('wsSubmit').disabled = false  is to enable and document.getElementById('wsSubmit').disabled = true to disable - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ymMyqz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the attribute.

```js
document.getElementById('wsSubmit').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

As mentioned in the comments, a duplicate Id would case this functionality to fail.

Comment: Can also target the property as OP is doing

Comment: In which case there would be some other error that wasn't mentioned. I actually didn't realize you could use the property directly, `removeAttribute` is the more common way, I'd think.

Comment: I am wondering if it is something with how I called document.getElementById().  Here is an example of how I called it 3 lines above the current call ```document.getElementById(butId).disabled = true;```.  This one works perfectly but when I explicitly name the button it seems to break.

Comment: @Kevin `getElementById` expects you to give the `id` value of the html element. So button name shouldn't work ..

Comment: @jhpratt Yes it was! It was present in a different partial view that should not have been rendered until after that button click.  Thanks for the persistence.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it! IDs should definitely be unique, or else things like that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

> [Visible controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) have a `disabled` property which, except for menus and menuitems, is normally preferred to use of the attribute, as it may need to update additional state.

A small demo:

```html
<!-- Checkbox enables/disables the button -->
<label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" label="Enable button" onclick="document.getElementById('buttRemove').disabled = ! this.checked">Enable/Disable the button</label>
<hr>
<button id="buttRemove" label="Remove All" disabled="true">Button</button>
```

Back to your example. The first 2 example of code which is really same, if I don't consider the `''` and `""`.. You want it to be set as `true`, when want to enable them like:

```
document.getElementById('wsSubmit').disabled = true;
document.getElementById("wsSubmit").disabled = true;
```

This should work. If doesn't work, then probably your page has duplicate ID to another element which comes after this `<button>` element in the DOM.