# how to prevent user to open the two icons together .. he must close one to open the other

Tags: icons

if I have Two icons in my Website, how can i prevent user if he open one of them can't open other if he close the opened icon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button when one is clicked on, or you could create a variable that prevents the button from preforming the action it normally preforms.
See: [Disabling and enabling a html input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button)

Comment: i know the concept but i can't know how to do this

Comment: @AmrElsayed Can I know what framework you use? I might be able to pull something from the web

Comment: i don't use any framework i built this site with HTML CSS JS only without any framework

Comment: @AmrElsayed Got something. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).